# Question about Hahn-Banach separation Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

So here is my question,

I am just reading about the Hahn-Banach separtion Theorem and there is one case where a question appeared, namely,

Let $X$ be a normed $\mathbb R$ vectorspace and let $A,B$ be convex, non empty disjoint sets.

i) If $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed then there exists $f\in X^*$ and $c\in\mathbb R$ such that

$$\sup_{a\in A}f(a)<c<\inf_{b\in B}f(b)$$

My question now is if we can switch the assumptions about $A,B$ to obtain the same result i.e

If $A$ is closed and $B$ compact then there exists $f\in X^*$ and $c\in\mathbb R$ such that

$$\sup_{a\in A}f(a)<c<\inf_{b\in B}f(b)$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the version of the separation theorem that you wrote (I mean the case when one set has to be compact and the second one closed) requires also that $X$ is locally convex.

The answer is yes, you just take $-f$ i.e.
$$\sup f(A)<c<\inf f(B)$$

$f\rightarrow -f$

$$\sup -f(A)<c<\inf -f(B) \iff -\inf f(A)<c<-\sup f(B)$$
and multiplying by $-1$ we get $$ \inf f(A)>-c>\sup f(B)$$